# Why can't Stream.flatMap accept a collection?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Given the following as an example of data classes:

```
class Country {

    List<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Region> getRegions() {
        return regions;
    }

}

class Region {

    String getName() {
        return "some name";
    }

}
```

Presuming I would have a List of Countries

```
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I wanted to Stream those to their Regions and their corresponding names I would like to do the following:

```
    countries.stream().flatMap(Country::getRegions).map(Region::getName)...
```

However that code does not compile since the return value of "getRegions" is a Collection (List) as opposed to a Stream, which the flatMap Method accepts.
But since I know that any Collection can be streamed via its Collection.stream() Method that shouldn't be a problem. Still I am forced to write it as follows:

```
    countries.stream().flatMap(c -> c.getRegions().stream()).map(Region::getName)...
```

Which is (given a richer context) far less readable than the former.

Questions is, is there any reason, that I am missing out on, for this to be that bulky? I have plenty of examples in our framework at which I am forced to take that route, always leaving me with a sour taste.
(Guess I just have to add Kotlin to our projects and extend the Stream class with a flatMap Method that takes a Collection :p or do I?)

Comment: I also tried the following as it made sense in my head, obviously it did not compile:
Country::getRegions::stream

Comment: I agree that `flatMap` should accept a collection, but I'm not sure SO is going to be able to provide a definitive explanation, other than "the people that wrote it didn't write it that way".

Comment: "no" could also be an answer :)

Comment: Please, check if Collectors.groupingBy helps you. Some examples available at: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Comment: You could return a `Stream<Country>` from the method instead. Or add a method `regions` that does that.

Comment: You can still do `.map(Country::getRegions).flatMap(List::stream)`, but I don’t get why method references are considered so superior to a simple lambda expression…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A technical reason, which is not ideal but could be why this wasn't done. You can't overload on a generic type in Java.

They need to support

```
 Stream.flatMap(Function<Object, Stream<X>> function)
```

which means they can't overload it with

```
 Stream.flatMap(Function<Object, Collection<X>> function)
```

as these two methods have the same signature after erasure.

They could add a method

```
 Stream.flatMapCollection(Function<Object, Collection<X>> function)
```

or

```
 Stream.flatMapIterable(Function<Object, Iterable<X>> function)

 Stream.flatMapI(Function<Object, Iterable<X>> function)
```

but it wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: Yes, if those methods were added it would be an improvement.

Comment: @khelwood it might not be any shorter.  Ideally they would add support for rarefied types and overloading on generics.

Comment: That answer is actually satisfying. Or rather it provides a valid explanation. Thanks

Comment: `flatCollection` and `flatArray` are provided in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).